# instantiating inside of onCreate compared to outside of it. why?

Tags: android, instantiation, android-lifecycle

most every example of Android code is done like example 2 shown below,  why is that so much better than what is shown in examaple 1?

example 1

```
    class TestActivity extends Activity() {

    HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass();

    EditText extiText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    }
```

example 2

```
    class TestActivity extends Activity() {

    HelperClass helperClass;

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    helperClass = new HelperClass();

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass();
```

But you can't do

```
 EditText extiText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

like example 1.

Because the layout file in loaded when `onCreate` in called for `setContentView(R.layout.layout);` and because `R.id.editText1` is a part of this layout, you have not access to it until layout gets loaded.

Read about [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: yes, I forgot about that, the fact that the layout file must be loaded before the editText is loaded